# Is the condition in a for loop evaluated each iteration?

Tags: c#, .net, loops

When you do stuff like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; ++i )
```

is collection.Count called on every iteration?

Would the result change if the Count property dynamically gets the count on call?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes Count will be evaluated on every single pass.  The reason why is that it's possible for the collection to be modified during the execution of a loop.  Given the loop structure the variable i should represent a valid index into the collection during an iteration.  If the check was not done on every loop then this is not provably true.  Example case

```
for ( int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++ ) {
  collection.Clear();
}
```

The one exception to this rule is looping over an array where the constraint is the Length.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < someArray.Length; i++ ) {
  // Code
}
```

The CLR JIT will special case this type of loop, in certain circumstances, since the length of an array can't change.  In those cases, bounds checking will only occur once.

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2005/04/23/411321.aspx

Comment: What if I resize the array inside the loop?

Comment: @Henk, yes that's part of the heuristic which determines if they can special case this loop.

Comment: @Jared: But Array has a static Resize method, right? That's what I meant, althoug probably assigning a new array. Also when you said "that's part of the heuristic", you mean the compiler recognizes this too?

Comment: @Jaredpar, I'm starting to have second thoughts - aren't we confusing this with the bounds-check optimization?  The Length property gets translated into a ldlen opcode, I'd call that inlining.

Comment: @Joan, yes there is a Resize but it creates a new array.  Note the first parameter is taken by reference.

Comment: @Henk, it's a little bit of both. The JIT will only do a single bound check here in the optimized scenario.  In the non-array scenario it will do N bound checks which require N property evals.

Comment: @Jared: Do you know why it's taken by ref? I don't know why it's defined like that?

Comment: @Joan, it's because array's cannot be resized at all.  It takes it byref because it makes a copy of the array and returns the copy back. So it only **appears** to resize the array.

Comment: Does string.Length have the same behaviour in a for loop?

Comment: Another reason is that you can do other things than looping through collections. E.g. `for (int p = capacity; !IsPrime(p); p++) { }` ensures `p` to be prime.

Comment: "_The reason why is that it's possible for the collection to be modified during the execution of a loop_" that's an _advantage_ of re-evaluating every loop, but I think the _reason_ (why it _has_ to be that way) is because `i < collection.Count` is just a boolean and the loop is going to repeat until it's `false`. If you enter the loop with a `true` and never check again, the loop would never exit.

Answer (score 16):

Count would be evaluated on every pass.  If you continued to add to the collection and the iterator never caught up, you would have an endless loop.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> intCollection = new List<int>();
            for(int i=-1;i < intCollection.Count;i++)
            {
                intCollection.Add(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

This eventually will get an out of memory exception.

Comment: Doesn't C# stop you from modifying a collection while iterating through it?  Or does that only happen in for each loops?

Comment: That only happens when you use Enumerators

Comment: @jeffamaphone - I thought the same thing, but wrote a small program that demonostrated it doesn't.  Interesting.

Comment: The OP doesn't say what collection is, but I used a List<> for my test.

Answer (score 4):

Yes count is checked at every call from the first iteration after the initialization of i to the last iteration where the check fails and the for loop is exited.  You can modify the collections count if you want but realize you could end up in an endless loop.

Answer (score 4):

Like the other answers here: Yes, in principal.

There is (at least) one noticeable exception, array.Length. In

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) a[i] = ...;
```

The Length property will only be evaluated once. This is a optimization that is hardwired into the compiler. There might be others like that (in the future) but only if it is guaranteed not to make a difference in observable behavior.

Comment: The compiler in question is the *JIT* compiler as far as I know though - not the C# compiler.

Comment: @John: Not sure, both compilers know the array is fixed. By looking at the IL I'd guess it's the C# compiler.

Comment: What if I resize the array inside the loop?

Comment: @Joan... why don't you try it - it takes like 60 seconds to build a little test app like what I showed above.  New project, console app...

Comment: I can try it, but I am on my friend's pc. Could use the snipper compiler, but don't wanna install stuff.

Comment: To be explicit, the condition is still evaluated, but the Length parameter is never updated.   It is still evaluated each iteration.  If you had `true` as the condition, it would still be evaluated each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Side note, this is NOT checked for every interation in VB.

Unlike C#, VB caches the result of the collection.Count.

EDIT:

The literal VB version of the C# for loop is:

```
Dim i = 0
Do While i < collection.Count
    'code goes here
    i+=1
Loop
```

Comment: So is it broken if you change the collection while iterating?

Comment: If you want to change the collection while looping, you need to use a loop.