# For Loop isnt being fully completed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a For Loop which handles taking cards from the master deck, and putting them in a random order into the players deck. The code is:

```
for(int a = 0; a < deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Count; a++){
        int b = Random.Range(0, deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Count);
            if(!PlayerDeck.Contains(deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer[b])){
            PlayerDeck.Add(deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer[b]);
            deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.RemoveAt(b);
        } 
    }
```

There are 16 cards in the master deck, but this for loop only does 8. Can someone figure out why? Originally, it was adding some cards multiple times, which is why I added the '!PlayerDeck.Contains' statement. I have no idea why it's only doing 8 of 16.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Count` is getting smaller at each iteration. Try this instead:

```
while (deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Count > 0) {
    int b = Random.Range(0, deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Count);
    PlayerDeck.Add(deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer[b]);
    deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.RemoveAt(b);
}
```

I removed the conditional, because it shouldn't be necessary. (Unless the starting deck has duplicates? If so, just put it back in.)

Comment: I do like the way intention expressed by using the while loop - makes clear that DeckAllCardsPlayer is being reduced, and to keep going until it's empty.

Answer (score 3):

You start off with 16 cards, but remove one each time.

As a result, although a decrease by one each iteration, the value of `deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Count` goes **down**.

After 8 iterations, `a` is 7, but the size of `DeckAllCardsPlayer` has been reduced to 8. Hence the loop terminates on the next turn.

One way to work around would be to take the count up front and store in an integer:

```
int totalCards = deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Count;
for(int a = 0; a < totalCards; a++){
    ... etc.
```

Although there are many other ways, depending on the logic that you want to expose.

This question may be enlightening : [Is the condition in a for loop evaluated each iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655373/is-the-condition-in-a-for-loop-evaluated-each-iteration)

Answer (score 1):

The upperbound or limit of the loop is changing as you remove cards from deck.
To fix it with just 2 line code change,
Try this

```
int count = deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Count;
for(int a = 0; a < count; a++){
        int b = Random.Range(0, deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Count);
            if(!PlayerDeck.Contains(deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer[b])){
            PlayerDeck.Add(deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer[b]);
            deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.RemoveAt(b);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `PlayerDeck` & `deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer` are both lists then just do this:

```
PlayerDeck.AddRange(deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.OrderBy(x => Random.value));
deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Clear();
```

Then you don't have to worry about removing elements while you iterate (which you should never do).

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Count;
for(int a = 0; a < count; a++){
        int b = Random.Range(0, deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Count);
            if(!PlayerDeck.Contains(deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer[b])){
            PlayerDeck.Add(deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer[b]);
            deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.RemoveAt(b);
        } 
    }
```

You must use count variable. Because `deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.Count` will be changed after run `deckManager.DeckAllCardsPlayer.RemoveAt(b)`. I hope it will work for you.